# Laravel MySql Driver Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am using Laravel 5.0, running on Centos 7/Apache. Whenever I attempt to access my site, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 11270:
Driver [mysql] not supported.

in Manager.php line 92
at Manager->createDriver('mysql') in Manager.php line 62
at Manager->driver() in StartSession.php line 116
at StartSession->getSession(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 101
at StartSession->startSession(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 56
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 55
```

I have a MariaDB backend, which was working fine prior to today. However, today, it errors. I haven't made any changes to the database configuration. I've confirmed that php-mysql, as well as the PDO driver for MySql are installed. Does anyone know why am receiving this error?

Comment: Although you've checked this, "Could not find driver" means it can't find the PDO driver connector to connect to MySQL. Can you confirm that you have `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in your php.ini? Also check that there's no other php config overriding that file.

Comment: The module is loaded. Here's the relevant portion from phpinfo().

Comment: PDO
    PDO support enabled
    PDO drivers mysql, sqlite
    
    pdo_mysql
    PDO Driver for MySQL enabled
    Client API version 5.5.44-MariaDB
    
    Directive Local Value Master Value
    pdo_mysql.default_socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Try to call `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: I've updated the original post with the error message post clear-compiled.